# How can i make this border little tighter in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

here is my unfinished web design:
[my web design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO909.png)

so as i said before i want to make the outer border little tighter. it's like i can make it tighter in the height by throwing them 
's, but i can't really do it for the width so if you experience with that sort of thing please give me the write code to write i will appreciate that.

here is my html code if you wanted to help me out :
https://hastebin.com/emebozihez.xml

again thanks alot if you make it till here

Comment: I don't quite understand you. Do you want to reduce center div size ?

Comment: yes, i want to make the div shorter to the center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't you tried these ? doesn't it work the way you want it to ? Just added :        `margin: auto; width: 70%;`

```
 #example3 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: auto; 
  width: 70%; 
  background: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: 10px 10px;

  background-position: 50% -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the width as a percentage and centering it. Perhaps something like this:

```
#example3 {
  width: 75%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```